# Unable to call `spree_current_user` inside rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am building a mountable rails (4.0.13) engine to add some functionalities to my existing spree app.

my `app/engines/my_engine/app/controllers/my_engine/application_controller.rb`

```
module MyEngine
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include Spree::Core::Engine.routes.url_helpers
    include Spree::Core::Engine.helpers
    include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers
  end
end
```

Inside one of the controllers of the engine - `app/engines/my_engine/app/controllers/my_engine/some_controller.rb` I have

```
require_dependency "my_engine/application_controller"

module MyEngine
  class SomeController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_user, except: :destroy
    .
    .
    private
    def find_user
      @user = spree_current_user
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting `undefined local variable or method 'spree_current_user'`!!

what should I do to make use of spree helpers inside my engine? Any help much appreciated

Comment: try adding this to your application controller `include Spree::AuthenticationHelpers`

Comment: @Sajin adding `include Spree::AuthenticationHelpers` fixed the problem.. many thanks

Comment: should i add it as an answer?

Comment: @Sajin you should, might help others as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to application_controller.rb

```
include Spree::AuthenticationHelpers
```